# How to attach sources to scala sbt project at Intellij Idea?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I am new at scala. And for start I want to use ***Intellij 13.1.5 IDE***.

However IDE can't attach sources. Here is how it looks for `AnyVal`:

[image]

`Search at internet` can't find any source.

I tried `Attach sources` and attach unpacked scala archive. It doesn't work either.

**UPDATE:**

Here is sbt configuration:

```
name := "scalatest-selenium"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.sourceforge.htmlunit" % "htmlunit" % "2.14",
  "org.seleniumhq.selenium" % "selenium-java" % "2.42.2",
  "org.scalacheck" % "scalacheck_2.10" % "1.11.4" % "test",
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.0" % "test"
)

testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-u", "target/test-reports")
```

***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: Is it only for `AnyVal` (or `Any`/`AnyRef`/`Unit`/`Nothing`)? Those are without a real source file, mostly compiler constructs. Otherwise -according to [this tutorial](http://www.plotprojects.com/create-an-intellij-idea-project-with-library-sources-attached/)-, you need to add `withSources()` to the dependencies in sbt.

Comment: @GáborBakos Hense which scala class should I check to verify that sources are attached?

Comment: Probably [`scala.App`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.6/src/library/scala/App.scala#L1). Hmm. It seems I was wrong and these classes ([AnyVal](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.6/src/library/scala/AnyVal.scala#L1)) already have sources. Not sure what is the problem could you share your sbt configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get rid of this trouble at the following way:

removed the `.sbt` directory in your **Home Folder**.

When you run sbt again, the new folder is created in the correct format and the error goes away.